# Retrieve all items from a SharePoint Field Choice Column

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am playing around with a SharePoint server and I am trying to programmatically add a service request to microsoft's call center application template. So far, I have had pretty good success. I can add a call for a specified customer and assign a specific support tech:

```
private enum FieldNames
{
    [EnumExtension.Value("Service Request")]
    ServiceRequest,
    [EnumExtension.Value("Customer")]
    Customer,
    [EnumExtension.Value("Service Representative")]
    ServiceRepresentative,
    [EnumExtension.Value("Assigned To")]
    AssignedTo,
    [EnumExtension.Value("Software")]
    Software,
    [EnumExtension.Value("Category")]
    Category
}
private void CreateServiceCall(string serviceCallTitle, string customerName, string serviceRep)
{
    SPSite allSites = new SPSite(siteURL);
    SPWeb site = allSites.AllWebs[siteName];
    SPListItemCollection requestsList = site.Lists[serviceRequests].Items;
    SPListItem item = requestsList.Add();

    SPFieldLookup customerLookup = item.Fields[FieldNames.Customer.Value()] as SPFieldLookup;

    item[FieldNames.ServiceRequest.Value()] = serviceCallTitle;

    if (customerLookup != null)
    {
        using (SPWeb lookupWeb = allSites.OpenWeb(customerLookup.LookupWebId))
        {
            SPList lookupList = lookupWeb.Lists.GetList(new Guid(customerLookup.LookupList), false);
            foreach (SPListItem listItem in lookupList.Items)
            {
                if (listItem[customerLookup.LookupField].ToString() != customerName) continue;

                item[FieldNames.Customer.Value()] = new SPFieldLookupValue(listItem.ID, customerName);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    SPUserCollection userCollection = site.SiteUsers;
    if (userCollection != null)
    {
        foreach (SPUser user in userCollection)
        {
            if (user.Name != serviceRep) continue;

            item[FieldNames.AssignedTo.Value()] = user;
            break;
        }
    }

    item.Update();

    site.Close();
    allSites.Close();
}
```

I added two custom columns (category, software) to the default list:

[image]

I populated both of these columns inside of SharePoint, now I want to retrieve that data so I can use it in the code snippet I posted to assign the proper category/software etc to the call. I have not been able to get the list in the code, I have tried using a `item["Software"]`, `site.Lists["Software"]` and a couple of others, but so far all I have come up is `null`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SPFieldMultiChoice` and related fields have a `Choices` property:

```
SPFieldMultiChoice software = item.Fields[FieldNames.Software.Value()] as SPFieldMultiChoice;
StringCollection softwareChoices = software.Choices;
```

If you need to set a value on the field, use the `SPFieldMultiChoiceValue` type:

```
SPFieldMultiChoiceValue values = new SPFieldMultiChoiceValue();
values.Add("Choice 1");
values.Add("Choice 2");
item[FieldNames.Software.Value()] = values;
```

Comment: This example demonstrates retrieving the `SPFieldMultiChoice` object from an `SPListItem` -- note that you can also get this object from an `SPList`, which for me was more useful because I wanted to access the Choices property after I get a List reference, but before I began iterating the List's items.

Just access the `SPList.Fields` property exactly the way `item.Fields` is being accessed in the example.